# Image isn't responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, image, next.js, tailwind-css

I am remaking a friends website in Next.js with Tailwind and I am having some problems with the background Image. It looks good in browser, chrome and safari, full window and phone variant but I can't manage to make it look good on iPhone. It compresses itself only on the phone.  Any ideas as to why? I have attached how it looks on the browser when it's in phone mode on browser and the last one is on the actual site on iPhone . I have also attached the code for this. Maybe i missed something big idk.. I would really appreciate the help. Let me know if you need more details about this

```
.custom-img2 {
  background-image: url('https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/57becd489de4bb4083a32846/1474057401289-YVPRNRZCTFWWCCZXT8DE/ccro-weee.png?format=2500w ') ;

}
```

```
<div>
      <div className='flex items-center justify-center h-screen mb-12 bg-fixed bg-center bg-cover custom-img2 sm:custom-img2 md:custom-img2 lg:custom-img2'>
       <div className=' top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 bg-black/70 z-[2]' />
      <div className='p-5 text-white z-[2] mt-[-10rem] l '>
        <h2 className='text-5xl font-bold  '>About Us</h2>
        <p className='py-5 text-xl '></p>
      </div>
      </div>
      {/* Overlay */}
.............
..............
...............
.............
</div>
```

[image: Phone mode in gogle chrome (localhost)]

[image: Zoomed in on Iphone (actual site )]

I tried playing with Tailwind screens and also with next/image for a whole day but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

`sm`, `md`, `lg` specify how you want styling to change at different screen sizes since Tailwind designs for mobile first so adding these screen sizes isn't necessary.

Not sure what's causing your image to show the way it does but i used the `bg` property in tailwind and it came out fine on different devices.

```
<div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen mb-12 bg-fixed bg-center bg-cover bg-[url('https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/57becd489de4bb4083a32846/1474057401289-YVPRNRZCTFWWCCZXT8DE/ccro-weee.png?format=2500w')]">
        <div className=" top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 bg-black/70 z-[2]" />
        <div className="p-5 text-white z-[2] mt-[-10rem] l ">
          <h2 className="text-5xl font-bold  ">About Us</h2>
          <p className="py-5 text-xl "></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve this on one of my sites for months, and I have finally found a solution to this issue.

In order to properly make your image responsive on iPhones, you'll need to add both of the following classes: `class="bg-contain bg-cover"`

Optionally, depending on how you want your image to be displated, you may also want to add `bg-local` and `bg-center`. Here is a working reponsive image from a snipped of my own code:

`<div class="h-screen bg-cover bg-center bg-local md:bg-fixed bg-contain bg-no-repeat md:bg-cover md:bg-center md:mb-[-40px] max-w-screen-sm md:max-w-none bg-image-1" style="background-image: url('{% static 'about/image_1.JPG' %}'">`

Your code editor may highlight this and give you a warning that the two classes provide the same CSS. Ignore this warning, as several hours of trial and error have proved this to be the only way to make large images responsive on iPhone using Tailwind CSS.